# como se convierte de str a float ¿?

Tags: python, float

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from suds.client import Client
import time
import json


class ClassName(object):


    fecha = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    def trm(self, fecha):
        try:
            wsdl_url = 'https://www.superfinanciera.gov.co/SuperfinancieraWebServiceTRM/TCRMServicesWebService/TCRMServicesWebService?WSDL'
            client = Client(wsdl_url, location=wsdl_url, faults=True)
            trm =  client.service.queryTCRM(fecha)
            response = json.dumps(trm.value)
            rate = float(response)
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e)

        return rate

    print trm('rate')
    print type(trm('rate'))
```

el resultado es:

```
   TypeError: trm() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: EL casting es correcto. Estás usando mal `type`, `type('rate')` retorna el tipo de `'rate'`, una cadena. Deberías ser en todo caso `print type(trm('rate'))` para obtener el tipo del objeto retornado por la función.

Comment: A todo esto, ¿el argumento `date` que utilidad tiene? No lo usas en la función, que externamente solo usa la variable `time`, global y que siempre tendrá el valor asignado cuando se importa o ejecuta el módulo no el tiempo en el momento de llamar a la función. Como recomendación, no uses `time` como nombre para la variable, estás solapando el módulo `time` con ello. Tampoco deberías usar `trm` como variable local en la función, este es el identificador de la propia función, aunque a no ser que usaras recursión o algo así no causará problemas , como mínimo es confuso. Un saludo.

Comment: hice el cambio en el codigo, si imprime tipo float, gracias... pero agregue una clase y ahora todo me da error.

Comment: Debes llamar al método con `self.trm()` dentro de la clase o `instancia.trm()` (`ClassName().trm()`)  fuera. El argumento `fecha` sobra, si es un atributo de la clase simplemente sustituye `...queryTCRM(fecha)` por `..queryTCRM(self.fecha)`¿La fecha debe ser la del momento en que se llama al método o función (y por tanto cambiar cada vez que se llama a la función) o cuando se instancia la clase (y por tanto ser la misma para todas las llamadas al método en esa instancia)?¿Debe ser la fecha la misma para todas las instancias de la clase (porque ahora es un atributo de clase no de instancia)?

Answer (score 0):

No se porque usas del como primer argumento "self" si no estás dentro de una clase 
El error te dice que la función toma 2 argumentos y tu solo le das fecha
Vamos que quites self